# Google Cloud Messaging apache tomcat not working

Tags: android, apache, web-applications, tomcat6, google-cloud-messaging

I am making GCM service in my app, and following this tutorial

http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-steps-to-run-gcm-demo.html

but on step 8, i am getting The requested URL /gcm-demo was not found on this server." on supplied URL  localhost/gcm-demo

I searched alot can't figure out whats the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try to connect to http://localhost:8080 ? Do you see the Tomcat home page?

Comment: When i type only localhost it shows /webapp folders with links. When i type localhost:8080 it shows "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080"

Comment: Sounds like Tomcat hasn't started then. You should see Tomcat's home page with a cartoon cat logo.

Comment: When i type localhost:80 it again shows /webapp folder contents.. I got Listen 80 in httpd.conf I am using Apche tomcat 6.0.26 Please help.

Comment: Have you installed Apache Tomcat or Apache Webserver?

Comment: How to know that, actually it was preinstalled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27620/discussion-between-madhur-rampal-and-nickt)

Comment: Well httpd.conf is a config file for the webserver (http server) default port is 80. Tomcat is a servlet/jsp container default port 8080. That demo definitely needs Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Default is port 8080, have you tried to use the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/gcm-demo
```

Comment: Yes i tried, but i get Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080 What i should do next?

Comment: Difficult for me to help without more information, this can be several things. For example: 1) make sure the server is up and running, 2) are you using the correct URL, check things like port number and context root

Comment: In which file they are? Httpd.conf?

Comment: I think the default context root in Tomcat is the war name, without the file extension.